# How to map {Ctrl  0,-,=} keys in vim?

Tags: mapping, keyboard-shortcuts, vim, ubuntu-12.04

My keyboard's layout(2nd row):

<kbd>`</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>...<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>

I want to map function calls to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>=</kbd>.

This is the function I created:

```
" it doesn't work
nnoremap <C-=>  :call IncFontSize(+1)<CR>

" it works
nnoremap <C-->  :call IncFontSize(-1)<CR>

" it doesn't work
nnoremap <C-0>  :call IncFontSize(0)<CR>

fun! IncFontSize(inc)
    if !exists('+guifont')
        return
    endif
    let s:defaultfont = 'Ubuntu Mono 12'
    if a:inc==0 || empty(&guifont)
        let &guifont = s:defaultfont
        return
    endif
    let &guifont = substitute(&guifont, '\d\+$', '\=submatch(0)+'.a:inc, '')
endfun
```

How can I map function calls to these keys?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice how in command-line mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>_</kbd> results in `^_`, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd> yield nothing.

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, differentiating this as well as many other key combinations (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Letter</kbd> vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Letter</kbd>) unfortunately isn't possible today, even in GVIM. This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. [link](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8)

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Answer (score 1):

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fast_window_resizing_with_plus/minus_keys

just only `+` and `-` …… no alias name

```
:nmap + :echo "hello world"<CR>
```

Is it what you want ?

Comment: found one: http://superuser.com/questions/226438/get-os-x-terminal-app-to-accept-ctrl-for-vim